# Theme Programmatically set. How to reload Activity to apply

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes, actionbarsherlock

How can I apply the Theme without restarting the whole App? If I do it with `startActivity(getIntent()); finish();` the Activity quits and dont restart. Is it possible to simply restart / recreate the Activity to apply the theme?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is in the incorrect order.

```
    finish();
    intent = new Intent(this, <your_activity>.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is the correct order.

Theme can be set before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` is being called. You need to destroy the activity and create it again and call immediately `setTheme(THEME);` in onCreate()

Comment: Do you have a answer on this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686912/actionbarsherlock-restart-to-apply-theme-triggers-wrong-lifecycle-methods

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```