# ActionBarSherlock restart to apply theme triggers wrong lifecycle methods

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use a `SherlockFragmentActivity` with 3 tabs. Each of these tabs are containing a `SherlockFragment`.

If I restart my app (to apply a theme) with this code: (thanks to [Dante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857583/dante)!)

```
finish();
intent = new Intent(this, <your_activity>.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

the app shutsdown properly but if the app are starting again, the whole lifecycle methods of my fragments are get called. Everything works fine, but one needed `boolean` are set to false in `onDestroy` but the fragment arent destroyed. Means, the `boolean` is wrong.

Is there a way to fix? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the value somewhere,for example in the database or in the shared preferences.

Before you apply the `setTheme(THEME);` You have to retrieve that value.

This is the initial value:

```
public static int THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock;
```

First set the value (for example "dark") and restart the app:

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
try {
    db.open();
    db.UpdateOption("theme", "dark");
}
catch (Exception ex) {}
finally {
    db.close();
}
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActionBarTabsPager.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you get the new value and set the THEME

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
Cursor c = null;

try {
    db.open();
    c = db.GetOption(c, "theme");
    String theme = c.getString(1);
    if (theme.equalsIgnoreCase("dark")) {
        THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock;
    }
    else if (theme.equalsIgnoreCase("light")) {
        THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;
    }
    else if (theme.equalsIgnoreCase("darklight")) {
        THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {}
finally {
    try {
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.close();
                c = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
        db.close();
}
setTheme(THEME);
```

I have a tabel OPTIONS to save some settings. This can also be done with shared preferences of course.

Comment: Applying the theme works. It just the problem that my fragments after restart starting and instantly shutdown. For example I can't access the listview anymore.

Comment: I cant requery the listlayout. This makes me crazy. :D

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean. Can you rephrase the question please? Keep in mind: If you do a restart, you should finish the root activity. Then it is just like you close the app and start it again later. If it is possible post some code where the errors lie in your opinion.

Comment: The app dont get finished fast enough. I solved it, with a 800ms delay.