# Android App : Apply Color Theme Dynamically at Runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

In My Application I want to support such functionality where users can select color from the list (which is downloaded from WebService) and as User selects any color(say Orange) all the Buttons in my application will have background color as Orange.

I have checked solutions like http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html but with that I need to have different styles created with different color in my app.

My need is I only support one style only background colors need to be changed according selection and for that I don't want to fetch all my buttons at runtime and apply that color.

---

So please suggest any other better solutions to apply selected color to all the buttons in the application without fetching all buttons in activities and setting their background color.

Answer (score 2):

You could fill a `Bitmap` with a particular color.

```
private BitmapDrawable makeColorFillDrawable(int color, Drawable d) {
    Bitmap maskBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
    final int width = maskBitmap.getWidth();
    final int height = maskBitmap.getHeight();
    maskBitmap = null;

    final Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outBitmap);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    d.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    d.draw(canvas);
    d.setColorFilter(null);
    d.setCallback(null);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), outBitmap);
}
```

Save the color you fetch from your server in your `SharedPreferences`. Then subclass `Button` and apply the color fill drawable based on the value you saved. All you'd need to do then is replace `<Button.../>` in your XML with the path to your custom one.

Here's an example with the `ActionBar` icon.

```
    final Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
    getActionBar().setIcon(makeColorFillDrawable(Color.RED, d));
```

[image: Example]

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You create the drawable for background images, not text color. Aside from that, either way you're creating drawables, whether you do it from a style or using the method above.

Comment: You've got this all wrong. Subclass `TextView` and `Button`. Call `Button.setBackgroundDrawable` and apply the color fill drawable in the constructor based on the value you save. Then call `TextView.setTextColor` in the constructor based on the same value. Now all you have to do is replace the XML. Either way you're creating 50-70 views. You can't apply a **one** `Drawable` to 50-70 views. They each have their own whether you do that via a style or through code. They have 50-70 of them right now without you doing anything.

Comment: sorry for not understanding what you wanted to say,
That's nice way, I have been following to create my own Custom buttons and textview and using them in XML but with this approach the problem occurs when need to make one button in different color and other in different also as requirement changes I need to create all custom views instead of default. Have you also implemented the same approach in any app? how was your experience with approach to make custom views and using them all the way in development?

Comment: I wrote an app that uses a theme engine that allows people to create custom drawables and apply custom colors to the app. What I'm explaining is what I use in this app. Also, calling `maskBitmap = null` `Drawable.setColorFilter(null)` and `Drawable.setCallback(null)` are used to release any references used when creating the color fill drawable. At any rate, that's my two cents.

Comment: Thanks for your support adneal +1, I have one more question say I have subclass of button and using that in two places in screen say "Cancel" and "Ok" and I want to give different color based on their type or tag, how I should implement that? or I will need to make two different button subclasses?

Comment: Either way you're creating two drawables. I'd make one subclass and then change the color fill drawable based on whatever value you use to determine which `Button` is which.

Comment: yes surely I will mark it but not now, I want to keep this thread open for few more days to get other inputs.! I hope you wont mind it.! thanks for your support. Though I am thinking that I will need to use custom attribute too to pass the type/category of button from XML to identify which color should be applied, what you say is that a fine solution?